# Conditional formatting for highlighting top 2 values for each row for visibile cells only

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to highlight top 2 values for each row for visible cells only using conditional formatting in Excel macro. My range is dynamic, hence I am running a loop to arrive at the last cell of the range.

Here is my code:

```
With Sheets("pcSupplyChainAnalysis").Select
    For i = 2 To ctr
        Set rng = Range("C" & i & ":" & "I" & i).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        rng.FormatConditions.AddTop10
        rng.FormatConditions(rng.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
        With rng.FormatConditions(1)
            .TopBottom = xlTop10Top
            .Rank = 2
            .Percent = False
        End With
        With rng.FormatConditions(1).Interior
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Color = 255
            .TintAndShade = 0
        End With

        rng.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
    Next
End With
```

Ctr is a counter I am running to find the position of the last non blank cell, as my data has blank values too and I am copying it from another sheet using macro.

```
ctr = 2
Do While (ActiveSheet.Range("A" & ctr).Value <> "")
    ctr = ctr + 1

Loop
ctr = ctr - 1
ActiveSheet.Range("B2:I" & ctr).Select
Selection.Cut
Range("C2:J" & ctr).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

[image: My data looks like this:] Attached is the image of the format of my data. I want to highlight top 2 numbers for each row and ONLY FOR VISIBLE CELLS (as I am using some filters also in the range).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ShowTop2()
    Dim rng As Range, visibleRow As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("pcSupplyChainAnalysis")
        .Columns.FormatConditions.Delete
        Set rng = .UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    End With

    For Each visibleRow In rng.Rows
        If visibleRow.Row > 1 Then
            With visibleRow.FormatConditions
                .AddTop10
                .Item(.Count).SetFirstPriority
                With .Item(1)
                    .TopBottom = xlTop10Top
                    .Rank = 2
                    .Interior.Color = 255
                End With
            End With
        End If
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

---

An easier way to determine the last used row in column A:

`ctr = Worksheets("pcSupplyChainAnalysis").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row`

You don't need to `Select` anything for any of your actions